# How can I disable item id tooltips?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I've got a custom modpack and for some reason there are multiple item ID tooltips.  I've already disabled the ones from NEI, but I've never been able to figure out what other mods are adding these useless tooltips.  Does anyone know what other mods add these tooltips?

Screenshot:

[image]

Mod List:

```
1.7.10-HarderWildlife-15.26.1d.jar
1.7.10-HardLib-15.26.1a.jar
ae2stuff-0.5.0.56-mc1.7.10.jar
appliedenergistics2-rv3-beta-6.jar
Aroma1997Core-1.7.10-1.0.2.16.jar
AromaBackup-1.7.10-0.1.0.0.jar
autopackager-1.5.9a.jar
bdlib-1.9.4.109-mc1.7.10.jar
BetterBuildersWands-0.8.1-1.7.10r92+aec06c3.jar
BetterFoliage-MC1.7.10-2.0.15.jar
BetterSprinting  MC-1.7.10  v1.1.3.jar
Carpenter's Blocks v3.3.8.1 - MC 1.7.10.jar
carpentersblocks
ChickenChunks-1.7.10-1.3.4.19-universal.jar
Chisel-2.9.5.11.jar
CodeChickenCore-1.7.10-1.0.7.47-universal.jar
CoFHCore-[1.7.10]3.1.4-329.jar
Controlling-1.7.10-1.0.0.jar
cookingbook-mc1.7.10-1.0.140.jar
craftingtweaks-mc1.7.10-1.0.82.jar
CustomOreGen-1.7.10-1.2.26.jar
denseores-1.6.2.jar
Ding-MC1.7.10v2.jar
DragonAPI 1.7.10 V17c.jar
ElectriCraft 1.7.10 V17a.jar
EnderCore-1.7.10-0.2.0.39_beta.jar
EnderIO-1.7.10-2.3.0.429_beta.jar
EnderStorage-1.7.10-1.4.7.37-universal.jar
Ewy's Workshop-1.1.6.jar
ExtraCells-1.7.10-2.3.14b197.jar
extrautilities-1.2.12.jar
fastcraft-1.23.jar.disabled
FastLeafDecay-1.7.10-1.4.jar
FloodLights-1.7.10-1.2.8-137.jar
GraveStone Mod 0.7.10.3.jar
IguanaTinkerTweaks-1.7.10-2.1.6.jar
IGW-Mod-1.7.10-1.1.12-34-universal.jar
InventoryTweaks-1.59-dev-152.jar
ironchest-1.7.10-6.0.60.741-universal.jar
journeymap-1.7.10-5.1.4p2-unlimited.jar
JustEnoughCalculation-1.7.10-0.3.4.jar
Mantle-1.7.10-0.3.2b.jar
mcjtylib-1.8.1.jar
ModularArmour-1.7.10-1.0.18-41.jar
MouseTweaks-2.4.4-mc1.7.10.jar
neiaddons-1.12.14.40-mc1.7.10.jar
NEIIntegration-MC1.7.10-1.1.2.jar
NoMobSpawningOnTrees-1.2.0-mc1.7.10.jar
NotEnoughItems-1.7.10-1.0.5.120-universal.jar
NotEnoughResources-1.7.10-0.1.0-128.jar
OptiFine_1.7.10_HD_U_D8.jar
ProjectRed-1.7.10-4.7.0pre12.95-Base.jar
ProjectRed-1.7.10-4.7.0pre12.95-Integration.jar
ReactorCraft 1.7.10 V17a.jar
rftools-4.23.jar
RotaryCraft 1.7.10 V17c.jar
StorageDrawers-1.7.10-1.10.8.jar
TConstruct-1.7.10-1.8.8.jar
TiCTooltips-mc1.7.10-1.2.5.jar
VeinMiner-1.7.10-0.35.2.487+e134bd4.jar
Waila-1.5.10_1.7.10.jar
WailaHarvestability-mc1.7.10-1.1.6.jar
WAILAPlugins-MC1.7.10-0.2.0-25.jar
Wawla-1.0.5.120.jar
ZyinsHUD-(1.7.10)-v.1.3.9.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three "chisel:granite" lines are from EnderCore, InventoryTweaks, and Veinminer.  You can disable the one in the EnderCore config, but I can't find any way to disable the other two.

The (#0457/0) part is just the standard advanced tooltip, which you can disable with F3+H (pressed together at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

try writing f3+h, it removes tooltips from items in general